# How I can create user defined roles in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database-administration

I have a database in mongoDB 2.6.4 in which I want to restrict the user as per their level.I want to given read privileges to some user and insert/update privileges to some user on a particular database.Please let me know how I can create user defined roles and assign it to the user.I tried the below but it is not working user have still full privileges.

```
db.runCommand({createRole: "read",
               privileges: [
                   { resource: { db: "sample", collection: "" }, 
                     actions: [ "find" ] 
                   }],
               roles: [],
               writeConcern: { w: "majority" , wtimeout: 5000 }
             })
```

==================================================================================

```
db.addUser( { user : "read",
              pwd  : "read",
              roles:["read"]
        } )
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is a website for software developers. But permission handling on databases is a configuration issue which needs to be solved by a database administrator. I nominated your question for migration to https://dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: FYI -- In MongoDB 2.6.4, "read" is a built-in role http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#database-user-roles, so you don't need to create the role, you can just create the user, granting them the "read" role in the sample database.  Be sure that you're running mongod with --auth and when you connect, you need to authenticate the user.

Comment: I have already tried this but that user who got the read privileges is able to perform curd operation in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Use following command login as admin

```
use admin
db.createRole(
   {
     role: "appsRole",
     privileges: [
       { resource: { cluster: true }, actions: [ "serverStatus" ] }
     ],
     roles: []
   }
)
```

Above role will be created and granted privilege of server status. For more detail, kindly check mongodb documentation carefully.